# How to add background to JPanel and then add a JButton on that JPanel

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, imageicon

```
//Calling function
ImagePanel Panel_2 = new ImagePanel(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/kagarwal/Downloads/intacct_logo_standard_web.png").getImage());
Panel_2.add(new JButton());
Panel_2.revalidate();


//Called function
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

private Image img;

  public ImagePanel(String img) {
    this(new ImageIcon(img).getImage());
  }

  public ImagePanel(Image img) {
    this.img = img;
    Dimension size = new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
    setPreferredSize(size);
    setMinimumSize(size);
    setMaximumSize(size);
    setSize(size);
    setLayout(null);
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
  }
}
```

Requirement is: that JPanel2 needs to have a background image, and on top of that we need to add JButton. But, issue here is that the newly added JButton does not appears in the given JPanel, it only shows background image. Am i missing refresh ?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in paintComponent, where you only ask the graphics object to draw the image.
But you should call the superclass paintComponent method by invoking super.paintComponent() passing the graphics object, in order to have all the components of the panel correctly displayed.